# Django delete uploaded files in schedule if it is useless

Tags: django, bash, file-upload

I have a model in Django to keep uploaded photos properties  as

```
class Photo(models.Model):

file = models.FileField(storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT), upload_to='uploads')
header = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=200)
added_by = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=500)
isVerified = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
```

This model is created through a form chain, and for some reason sometimes the photo may be uploaded but because chain is not completed, it becomes useless.

I want to write a script to delete all such files (isVerified=False) and run it in certain schedule.

How should I write that script ? 
I may write a Bash script to reach all the files in a folder but how should I move on ?

Thanks

Comment: Never getting the unnecessary photos is far preferable to cleaning them up later for a number of reasons, like bandwidth use. Is there a reason you can't make the file upload the last step, or make uploading conditional on the completion of the other steps? If this extra data is just properties of the Photo, why not put them on the same form?

An even better solution might be to make the forms some type of JQuery slider, where you see the first form (file upload), click next, and the next "form" is displayed, and so on, and no POSTs actually occur until completion of the last step of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a python script, using Django to hit the database and get everything not verified.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
    # Assuming your settings are in the same directory, called settings.py.  
    # This is needed to tell django where to find the database
    # use "module syntax" - dots not slashes

from django.conf import settings
from models import Photo # Make sure this is after the os.environ call
for photo in Photo.objects.filter(isVerified = false):
    full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, photo.file.path)
    os.unlink(full_path)
```

Keep in mind I haven't tested this : )

Once you've sucessfully tested it, you could then run this every say 6 hours by putting it in your crontab.  Save it as say, `delete_unverified_files.py`, and run `crontab -e`.  In the file that appears, put:

```
0 */6 * * * python /path/to/delete_unverified_files.py
```

If you google crontab, you'll find a lot of examples of how to write one, if you're not familiar.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to use custom django-admin commands:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/

So crontab will just execute smth like this:
`... manage.py delete_unverified_files`